# VBO draws nothing

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer

I'm trying to render my stored data using VBOs. However, nothing is actually rendered, although no error is thrown by glGetError();

```
void Model::initDrawing()
{
    glewInit(); 

    glGenBuffers(1, &_bufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bufferID);

    const GLsizeiptr vertex_size = sizeof(_modelMesh->vertices);
    const GLsizeiptr normal_size = sizeof(_modelMesh->vertices);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_size+normal_size, 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    GLvoid * vbo_buffer = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
        memcpy(vbo_buffer, &_modelMesh->vertices[0], vertex_size);
        vbo_buffer += vertex_size;      
        memcpy(vbo_buffer, &_modelMesh->normals[0], normal_size);       
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL));
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL+vertex_size));       
}

void Model::draw()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bufferID);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, _modelMesh->vertices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL));

    GLenum err;
    while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        cerr << "OpenGL error: " << err << endl;
    }
}
```

where `Mesh *_modelMesh` consists of (among the others):

```
std::vector<Vertex4f> vertices;
std::vector<Normal3f> normals;
```

which are simply just vectors of numbers of `GLfloat` type:

```
typedef struct _vertex4f {
    Vertex3f vertex;
    GLfloat weight;
} Vertex4f;
typedef struct _vertex3f {
    GLfloat x, y, z;
} Vertex3f;
```

Is defining vectors and normals enough for drawing?

I'm also using light when rendering.

Comment: I assume `Vertex4f` are actually POD types and you have accounted for padding etc?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if I should use `glVertexPointer` as 4 numbers and 0 padding or as 3 numbers with padding 1. Question updated: `Vertex4f`, `Vertex3f` added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, your positions and normals are not sized correctly.

Their sizes should be something like `_modelMesh->vertices.size () * sizeof (GLfloat) * 4` and `_modelMesh->normals.size () * sizeof (GLfloat) * 3` respectively. They are not the same size.

You also do not want to use `sizeof (_modelMesh->vertices)`, because `vertices` is a templated container. That will not give you the size of its contained elements, just the size of the instantiated `std::vector <Vertex4f>` object (which is probably a couple of pointers).

Finally, I do not see anywhere in this code where you bind anything to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

Likewise, `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bufferID);` is not necessary in `Model::draw (...)`, because the only time the thing bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` matters is when you call `gl...Pointer (...)`. From that point on, it does not matter what, if anything is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`; its only purpose is to tell the Pointer command which buffer's memory the pointer is relative to.

Answer (score 2):

Settings made by calls to `gl…Pointer` are not persistent within the buffer. Either you contain them within a Vertex Array Object, or you set them right before the `gl…Draw` calls. Furthermore, yor call to `glDrawElements` looks like you're intending to fetch indices from a Vertex Element Array buffer. I don't see you generating one.

These changes are required:

```
void Model::initDrawing()
{
    glewInit(); 

    glGenBuffers(1, &_bufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bufferID);

    const GLsizeiptr vertex_size = sizeof(_modelMesh->vertices);
    const GLsizeiptr normal_size = sizeof(_modelMesh->vertices);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_size+normal_size, 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    GLvoid * vbo_buffer = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
        memcpy(vbo_buffer, &_modelMesh->vertices[0], vertex_size);
        vbo_buffer += vertex_size;      
        memcpy(vbo_buffer, &_modelMesh->normals[0], normal_size);       
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &element_bufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, element_bufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_size+normal_size, 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLvoid * element_buffer = glMapBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
       /* fill element buffer */
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}

void Model::draw()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bufferID);
    glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL));
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL+vertex_size));       

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, element_bufferID);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, _modelMesh->vertices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL));

    GLenum err;
    while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        cerr << "OpenGL error: " << err << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: so `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` buffer is required? Isn't it possible with `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` only?

Comment: @Dundee: You are passing a value of `NULL` for the pointer field in `glDrawElements (...)`. If you don't have something bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` when you make this call, GL will treat that pointer as an address in your program's memory. It will dereference a NULL pointer and chances are that's ***not*** what you want ;) Either use a pointer to actual memory, or an element array buffer.